# Using awk on all columns for just part of column content

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I trying to find a solution for the following. I have a list of gene IDs in my first column and in all the other columns the related GO terms. The number of columns behind each gene ID is therefor variable. As follows the first few lines:

```
TRINITY_DN173118_c0_g1  GO:0000139^cellular_component^Golgi membrane
TRINITY_DN49436_c2_g1   GO:0006351^biological_process^transcription, DNA-templated
TRINITY_DN47442_c0_g1   GO:0003677^molecular_function^DNA binding   GO:0006302^biological_process^double-strand break repair    GO:0006310^biological_process^DNA recombination
```

The GO terms are delimited with a tab. I want to keep the first column, with the IDs and all the columns that contain "biological_process". But how do I do that using awk, without a specific column to search in.

I basically want to use grep for columns, so was trying something with awk (but I am not experienced in awk at all):

`awk '/biological_process/'` -> I get the full line
`awk '{ print "biological_process" }'` -> I only get biological process

Can someone help me out? THanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please wrap up your code in CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: I tried to use <pre> and closing pre as well. But this returned constantly in an error. But this is the correct coding, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AWK:**

```
awk -F"GO:" '{printf "%s",$1}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/biological_process/)printf FS"%s",$i ;print ""}' file
```

1) `-F"GO:"` - use "GO:" string as separator

2) `{printf "%s",$1}` - print the first column (without new line)

3) `for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)` - run on all columns beside the first one

4) `($i~/biological_process/)`  - check if string exists in col

5) `printf FS"%s",$i`  - if string exists in column print the separator and the string

6) `print ""` - print new line

**input file used:**

```
  TRINITY_DN173118_c0_g1  GO:0000139^cellular_component^Golgi membrane
  TRINITY_DN49436_c2_g1   GO:0006351^biological_process^transcription, DNA-templated 
  TRINITY_DN47442_c0_g1   GO:0003677^molecular_function^DNA binding GO:0006302^biological_process^double-strand break repair GO:0006310^biological_process^DNA recombination
```

**output**

```
   TRINITY_DN173118_c0_g1  
   TRINITY_DN49436_c2_g1   GO:0006351^biological_process^transcription, DNA-templated
   TRINITY_DN47442_c0_g1   GO:0006302^biological_process^double-strand break repair GO:0006310^biological_process^DNA recombination
```

Thanks to [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) for the feedback , I have edit the Answer :).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm.. A lot to discover in the world of awk! :-)

Comment: @EdMorton
Just for sake of practice I tried to implement above code to my new job, using awk to just get the GO numbers like:

TRINITY_DN1213_c2_g1 GO:1234567 GO:1234756

Using the following code:
'code' awk -F"GO:" '{printf "%s",$1}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/GO:[0-9]{7}/)printf FS"%s",$i ;print ""}' 

But this results in only the first identifier column being printed.. Do you spot my mistake?

Comment: @shaiki siegal
Thanks for kindly letting me know Ed, now with the correct person in the comment

Answer (score 1):

another similar `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} 
             {line=$1; 
              for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/biological_process/) line=line OFS $i; 
              print line}' file

TRINITY_DN173118_c0_g1
TRINITY_DN49436_c2_g1   GO:0006351^biological_process^transcription, DNA-templated
TRINITY_DN47442_c0_g1   GO:0006302^biological_process^double-strand break repair        GO:0006310^biological_process^DNA recombination
```

Comment: @karafka
Same as above, to practice I tried to use your string now to only retrieve the GO terms: TRINITY_DN1213_c2_g1 GO:1234567 GO:1234756
But I did not succeed, what am I doing wrong?
'awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="GO:[0-9]{7}"} 
             {line=$1; 
              for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/GO:/) line=line OFS $i; 
              print line}' file

Comment: When you define GO as part of the field separator, it's no longer part of fields.